# find.find() and browser.find.highlightResults() not working for firefox 61 extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to make an extension for firefox v 61 using [find.find() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/find/find) and [find.highlightResults docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/find/highlightResults). I have added find as part of the permissions section on my manifest.json as suggested, and i tried the example script found on highlightResults, and it doesn't seem to be running.

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "find words",
  "version": "1.0",

 "description": "highlights words found on random website",

"icons": {
"48": "icons/border-48.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["test.js"]
}
],
"permissions": [
"webNavigation",
"webRequest",
"find"
]
}
```

and the code bit for test.js looks like this:

```
function found(results) {
 console.log(`There were: ${results.count} matches.`);
  if (results.count > 0) {
browser.find.highlightResults();
  }
}

browser.find.find("banana").then(found);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should use a background script instead of a content script.

Comment: tried with no luck, like this:   "background": {
    "scripts": ["test.js"]
  }